# It is possible to add label to zkoss tabbox?

Tags: java, zk

I have tabbox with several vertical tabs. I need to add labels between some tabs(or just make disabled tabs with this labels).
How can I do that?

Comment: You could try `<tab label="Hello there!" disabled="true" />`?

Comment: Konstantin, thank you. It is works. Now I just need to change style of disabled tabs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to  Konstantin V. Salikhov. This is solution 
`<tab label="Hello there!" disabled="true" />`